# Ussuri: QCOW2-Win10-Client won't boot after importing into OpenStack

Tags: openstack

Created Win10-QCOW2-Image using Virt-Manager on Epyc-Server-Infrastructure which runs also OpenStack Ussuri.

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 win_10_kvm64.qcow2 15G

virt-install --connect qemu:///system \
    --name Win10 --ram 4096 --vcpus 8 --cpu host-passthrough \
    --network network=default,model=virtio \
    --disk path=win_10_kvm64.qcow2,format=qcow2,device=disk,bus=virtio \
    --cdrom /media/win10/Win10_2004_German_x64.iso \
    --disk path=/media/win10/virtio-win.iso,device=cdrom \
    --vnc --os-type windows --os-variant win10
```

CPU Settings tried: CPU Pass-Through, kvm64 (Yes, this won't work anyway), emulations for Intel, Epyc-Emulations. The VM works fine in all cases when starting under Virt-Manager.
After Importing as Image into Ussuri, Win10 tries to repair itself. No chance to get it startet. Tried many different cpu_models. Same result

```
#Allowed values: kvm, lxc, qemu, uml, xen, parallels
    virt_type = kvm
    live_migration_flag=VIR_MIGRATE_UNDEFINE_SOURCE, VIR_MIGRATE_PEER2PEER, VIR_MIGRATE_LIVE, VIR_MIGRATE_TUNNELLED
    #cpu_mode = custom
    #cpu_models = kvm64,epyc
    #cpu_models = kvm64,Penryn,IvyBridge,Haswell,Broadwell,Skylake-Client
    cpu_mode = host-passthrough
```

The import of the QCOW2 was done by:

```
openstack image create --public --disk-format qcow2 --container-format bare --file win_10_kvm64.qcow2 Win10
```

Any ideas how to solve?

Comment: I'd start by comparing qemu command strings for the working virt-manager test and the failing OpenStack test.

Comment: It's been a while since we did that (maybe Liberty or so) but to be able to boot a Windows VM we had to import a virtio driver: https://docs.openstack.org/de/image-guide/windows-image.html. I haven't tested this in a while so there may be some workarounds necessary.

Comment: Yes, this is what we did. Please have a look at the first script. I include this driver as attached CD-ROM. And I installed it of course while setup was in progress.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that.